# Vertical line spacing versus vertical character spacing

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment

I made some sort of a "header" for a test to my students. The code I used was

```
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}Combinatorics -- 2018.2 \hfill  \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{logo.pdf}\end{flushleft}
\vspace{-0,3cm}
\hrule
\vspace{-0,3cm}
\begin{flushleft}\textbf{FIRST TEST}\hfill Prof$.$ Alessandro Gaio\end{flushleft}
\vspace{0.3cm}
```

which produced

[image]

But when I changed the text "Combinatorics" to "Differential Geometry"

```
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}Differential Geometry -- 2018.2 \hfill  \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{logo.pdf}\end{flushleft}
\vspace{-0,3cm}
\hrule
\vspace{-0,3cm}
\begin{flushleft}\textbf{FIRST TEST}\hfill Prof$.$ Alessandro Gaio\end{flushleft}
\vspace{0.3cm}
```

the presence of the character "y" in "geometry" produced this:

[image]

as you will notice, the space between "Differential Geometry" and the horizontal line has increased in comparision to what happened when "Combinatorics" was written.

So how could I avoid this to happen? I would like both the spaces to be like the small one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\hrule` allows for precise spacing, but `flushleft` is of a hindrance. Better using a horizontal box.

Since `\hrule` adds no vertical space above and below, you can precisely decide how much to put. The only thing to do is to remove the depth of the top line, which can be done by ending the paragraph (consisting of the single box) and back up by `\prevdepth`.

A macro is definitely the way to go, so if you want to change the spacing, you only have to fix the code for the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\assignmentheader}[3]{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
    \strut #1 -- #2\hfill
    \includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image}%
  }%
  \par\vspace{-\prevdepth}\vspace{0.5ex}
  \hrule\vspace{0.5ex}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{\textbf{#3}\hfill Prof.\ Alessandro Gaio}%
  \par
}
\begin{document}

\assignmentheader{Combinatorics}{2018.2}{FIRST TEST}

\bigskip

\assignmentheader{Differential Geometry}{2018.2}{FIRST TEST}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, if you don't want that the period in `Prof.` is considered sentence ending, type

```
Prof.\ Alessandro Gioia
```

and not the horrible `Prof$.$` `;-)`

The `showframe` package is just for showing the text block boundaries, remove it for the production version.

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX `\rule` command would have been positioned based on consistent baseline to baseline spacing, but as you have used the Tex primitive `\hrule` it is positioned immediately in the vertical list so affected by descenders. The simplest change starting from what you have would be to use

```
\mbox{\textbf{\smash{Differential Geometry}}}
```

where the `\smash`  macro hides the vertical extent of its content.